# UICollectionView Set First Opening index Number

Tags: set, uicollectionview, default, nsindexpath

I have an UICollectionView. This CollectionView opens to index number "0" but I want it to open to index number "2" . How do I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: cellHeight * 2), animated: false)
```

you can use this line in swift

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your collectionViewcell height (If scrolling is vertically)

you can add `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,cellHeight *2) animated:NO];`

in your `viewWillApear`